# $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$. Show $p=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ is solvable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$p$ is a prime while $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

Not sure how to deal with this question. It's obviously related to Lagrange's four-square theorem but here, the question asks about 'solvability' so how can I start to show that there are indeed integers that satisfy the given equation?

Would love any sort of hints :)

Comment: Maybe you can prove a bigger one: $\exists a, b, c, d \text{ s.t. } a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4k+3, k \in \Bbb{N}.$

Comment: not really sure how to deal with that problem too :(

Comment: Does $a, b, c, d$ have to be distinct integers?

Comment: Nope, that's not a requirement

Comment: You are asking to prove Lagrange's four square theorem (assuming that you know that every prime $\not \equiv 3\bmod 4$ is the sum of two squares, then using the multiplicativity of the norm on integer quaternions)

Comment: Is this the same as proving the theorem then? Actually, this is a subquestion before a question on the proof for the theorem...

Comment: @NoahXd Always showing bigger one is the best to solve the problem.